# HTTP get request from fetched object property - I need to wait?

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular and TypeScript, I have a dish-detail component -> dishes/:id

The fetched dish has a property called components (not good I didn't know Angular use this term) with an array of two properties:

- id: type string
- quantity: type number

I want to use the property id of components to fetch components from MongoDB (works on back-end).

My problem is that I have to wait for getDish() is done before I can run getComponentDetails(). I have tried async/await and .then on ngOnInit and getDish(), stuff in the component.html like trackBy, if then.

I just can't figure it out. See comments in provided code.

Here is dish-detail.component.ts:

```ts
export class DishDetailComponent implements OnInit{
  dish: Dish | undefined;
  id: string | undefined;
  component: any | undefined;
  components: any | undefined;
  currentComponent: any | undefined;
  componentDetails: [] = [];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
    private dishService: DishService,
    private componentService: ComponentService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = String(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('_id'));
    this.getDish();
    // executing getComponentDetails() here yields undefined error - dish not loaded yet
  }

  getDish(): void {
    this.dishService.getDishById(this.id!)
      .subscribe(dish => this.dish = dish);
    // executing getComponentDetails() here yields undefined error - dish not loaded yet
  }

  getComponentDetails(): void {
    console.log("in getComponentDetails...");
    this.dish!.components.forEach(function (value) {
      console.log(value.componentId);
    // here I will fetch component from ID and subscribe to variable
    // similar to getDish()
    })
  }
```

in dish-detail.component.html:

```html
<div *ngIf="dish" class="mt-4">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h2>{{ dish.name | uppercase }} Details</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="total-cost" class="form-label">Total Cost:</label>
        <span>{{ dish.totalCost }}</span>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="dish-name" class="form-label">Dish Name:</label>
        <input id="dish-name" [(ngModel)]="dish.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <h3>Components:</h3>
        <div class="mb3" *ngFor="let component of dish.components">
          <div class="card" *ngIf="component">
            <p>test</p>
            <div class="card-body" class="mb-3">
              <h5 class="card-title">Id:{{ component.componentId }}</h5>
              <!-- here I would like to get properties from the component of id component.componentId,
              lets call it componentDetails-->
              <!-- like componentDetails.name -->
              <div class="card-text">
                <p>Quantity: {{ component.componentQuantity }}</p>
                <!-- other properties like componentDetails.price -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <a class="btn btn-warning" (click)="goBack()">Go Back</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateDish()">Update</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteDish()">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">
        <p><b>Dish ID:</b> {{ dish._id }}
        <p><b>Created @</b> {{ dish.createdAt | date:'medium' }}</p>
        <p><b>Updated @</b> {{ dish.updatedAt | date:'medium' }}</p>
      </small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**How can I fetch data based on property after it loaded? How do I "wait"? Do I need a completely different approach?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I fetch data based on property after it loaded?

Create an observable stream from source to your template model then using async pipe to subscribe in the template (this also takes care of unsubscribing).

> How do I "wait"?

So you don't "wait" but create the (imperative as opposed to declarative) stream that will take the id and map to the view model taking in values from observable https along the way.

> Do I need a completely different approach?

The alternate approach I don't recommend is doing nested subscribes.

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so76876701?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { of, delay, switchMap, forkJoin, map } from 'rxjs';

/** Mock services with delays */
const dishService = {
  getDishById(id: string) {
    return of({
      name: 'Very expensive caviar',
      totalCost: 1_000_000,
      components: [
        {
          id: 'jufbvjh',
        },
        {
          id: 'woehfjb',
        },
      ],
    }).pipe(delay(1000));
  },
};
const componentService = {
  getComponentById(id: string) {
    return of({
      componentId: id,
      componentQuantity: Math.random(),
    }).pipe(delay(1000));
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngIf="vm$ | async as vm">
     <pre>{{ vm | json }}</pre>
    </ng-container>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  vm$ = dishService.getDishById('jbvhbfr').pipe(
    switchMap((dish) =>
      forkJoin(
        dish.components.map((c) => componentService.getComponentById(c.id))
      ).pipe(
        map((componentInfo) => ({
          ...dish,
          components: [...componentInfo],
        }))
      )
    )
  );
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I kind of understand what's going on. I manage to print *ngIf="vm$ | async as vm" with {{ vm | json }}.

I'm having a bit of a problem getting specific data from vm. I would like just to print vm.name, vm._name etc, but get an error: Object is of type 'unknown'.

Also: from the code I would think that the data from the components is entered in the array of components, the map-part. But it seems like the components array is null?

I also tried to get the actual data with the keyvalue pipeline, but with no success.

Comment: I played around with your stackblitz link and changed the data structure to follow mine more.. seems to work! will try to understand what's wrong with my code -_-

Comment: Feel free to ask another question if you’re facing a particular issue